# jquery sortable - allow only last item dropped in target li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have list of numbers, and two destination blocks. I would like to drop number to target block, but keep only last dropped item.

Here is the sample jsfiddle - [demo - which allows only one item drag](http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/R2bFu/1/)

Code -

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
    });

    $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        dropOnEmpty: false
    });

    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();

    $("#sortable3,#sortable4").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
        var $list = $(this);

        if ($list.children().length > 1) {
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

            //Move the existing one back to sortable1
            //Only keep the last moved element
        }
    });
});
```

In above example if user try to drag 2nd number to sortable3 or 4, it doesn't allow another number. The behavior I am expecting is if new number is dragged, the previous one should go back to sortable1 list (back to origin).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your sortreceive and use this instead

```
$("#sortable1").on("sortremove", function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.prependTo( ui.item.parent());
    $.each(ui.item.parent().children(), function(index, item) {
        if ( index > 0 )
            $(this).appendTo($("#sortable1"));
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/382dy/

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be as simple as

```
 $("ul.droptrue:not(:#sortable1)").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
    $(this).children().not(ui.item).appendTo("#sortable1")
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/382dy/11/)

No need for extra iterations